# How to force a gradle sub project to use root project's buildToolsVersion/compileSdkVersion?

Tags: android, gradle

Looking for some smart way of doing this only once e.g.

```
allprojects {
  android {
    buildToolsVersion '18.0.1'
    compileSdkVersion 18

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise I need to up this thing in every subproject (e.g. in referenced library like volley or viewpagerindicator) every time there's a new SDK update available.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the root project wouldn't contain code and hence you would use `subprojects`. Also you'll have to apply the Android plugin before the `android {}` block. Other than that, I'd expect this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I answered in another question:

I found a solution [here](https://plus.googleapis.com/wm/4/+Gon%C3%A7aloSilva/posts/3EYhtGdknij).

Will copy it here just in case:

In you root build.gradle add

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 20
    buildToolsVersion = "20.0.0"
}
subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate{
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will apply compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion to any android modules you have.

And in your main project's build.gradle change dependencies to this:

```
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
```

Basically you are defining them once and could use from anywhere.

Cheers.